# Finding all pairs of numbers in a collection whose sum is some particular number

Tags: c#, performance, algorithm

I had to write the method that extract all pairs of numbers from collection of numbers, which sum matches the particular number.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var inputCollection = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    var targetNumber = 12;

    var pairs = ExtractPairs.Extract(inputCollection, targetNumber);

    foreach (var pair in pairs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(pair.First + ", " + pair.Second);
    }
}

public class ExtractPairs
{
    public struct Pair
    {
        public int First;
        public int Second;
    }

    public static List<Pair> Extract(List<int> input, int targetNumber)
    {
        var pairs = new List<Pair>();
        var current = input[0];
        do
        {
            for (int i = current; i < input.Count; i++)
            {
                if (current + input[i] != targetNumber) continue;
                var pair = new Pair
                {
                    First = current,
                    Second = input[i]
                };
                pairs.Add(pair);
            }
            current++;
        } while (current < input.Count);

        return pairs;
    }
}
```

I think my algorithm should be more productive, but not sure in which way. Any suggestion and/or code will be helpful.

Comment: Will the input always be sorted or is that just your example?

Comment: This seems to be a variant of the problem that is found under the name of 'TwoSum' on many sites, with the change that *all* pairs are sought instead of any one pair. It would have been helpful if the *exact* problem description had been included...

Answer (score 7):

You haven't clarified what you're expecting your input to be but your code doesn't work unless the input is a set of positive integers starting at 1 and increasing 1 at a time.

For example:

```
var inputCollection = new List<int> { 5, 6, 7 };
var targetNumber = 12;

var pairs = ExtractPairs.Extract(inputCollection, targetNumber);
```

Clearly, 5 + 7 = 12 but your code returns no pairs! That's either a huge bug or the algorithm is expecting a very restricted input. I'd put my money on a huge bug.

---

Don't make structs with public mutable fields (unless you're in a very specific performance critical scenario). As pointed out in comments, I should have backed up this advice with some evidence. Here's an [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/441323/1402923) about it or simply quoting the [MS guidelines for struct design](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229031(v=vs.110).aspx)

> X DO NOT define mutable value types.
>
> Mutable value types have several problems. For example, when a property getter returns a value type, the caller receives a copy. Because the copy is created implicitly, developers might not be aware that they are mutating the copy, and not the original value. Also, some languages (dynamic languages, in particular) have problems using mutable value types because even local variables, when dereferenced, cause a copy to be made.

```
public struct Pair
{
    public int First;
    public int Second;
}
```

Make them `readonly` properties and add a constructor. I'd probably just use a `Tuple<int, int>` though.

---

Prefer formatting strings over concatenation:

```
Console.WriteLine(pair.First + ", " + pair.Second);
```

could be:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", pair.First, pair.Second);
```

In C#6 we also have string intperpolation:

```
Console.WriteLine($"{pair.First}, {pair.Second}");
```

In this simple case, the concatenation is actually fine. It's clear because it's short. As things become longer and more complex, the format string approach can make the final string clearer to see for a human. There are also a great many options for things like padding and formatting numbers and dates that are easily done in the format string.

Just an FYI, the concatenation is turned into a call to `string.Concat`:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(new[] { pair.First, ", ", pair.Second }));
```

Comment: @DarthGizka - I'll nuke my comments and update the question. Thanks for again your input. I didn't as much effort into this answer as I should have.

Answer (score 1):

I liked @RobH suggestion so much I just had to spend time coming up with an implementation.  Here is my version...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
//  var inputCollection = new List<int> { 5, 6, 7 };
    var inputCollection = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

    var targetNumber = 12;

    var pairs = ExtractPairs.Extract(inputCollection, targetNumber);

    foreach (var pair in pairs)
        Console.WriteLine($"{pair.Item1},{pair.Item2}");
}

public class ExtractPairs
{
    public static List<Tuple<int,int>> Extract(IEnumerable<int> input, int targetNumber)
    {
        int half = targetNumber / 2;
        var sorted = input.Where(n => n <= half).OrderBy(s => s);

        var pairs = new List<Tuple<int,int>>();
        foreach (var current in sorted)
        {
            var result = targetNumber - current;
            if (input.Where(n => n > current).Contains(result))
                pairs.Add(Tuple.Create(current, result));
        }

        return pairs;
    }
}
```

This can also be rewritten to defer the execution (I just love LINQ!)...

```
    public static IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int>> Extract(IEnumerable<int> input, int targetNumber)
    {
        var half = targetNumber / 2;
        return
            from current
            in input.Where(n => n <= half).OrderBy(n => n)
            let result = targetNumber - current
            where input.Where(n => n > current).Contains(result)
            select Tuple.Create(current, result);
    }
```

Comment: You are assuming that input numbers are unique, which is not necessarily given. `foreach` and Linq are very coarse-grained tools that lack precision, and this can easily seduce one into less precise thinking...

Comment: There was no indication by the OP as to what to do with duplicates so I assumed duplicates pairs would be rendered.  You can easily eliminate the duplicates by adding ".Distinct()" to the LINQ statements.

Comment: Will that even work for simple cases like input {5,5}, target 10? I doubt it. In an interview situation (where this variant of the TwoSum problem can be found) it would be fatal to make unwarranted assumptions, or to write code that doesn't deliver. If the code works only on restricted inputs then this must be documented, ideally with a suitable assertion, and one should be able to explain why it was reasonable to assume restricted inputs . However, writing correct code would be easier and simpler than writing brittle code together with code that asserts the required input restrictions.

Comment: The same principles apply outside of interview situations - i.e. work, coding challenges and so on - but sloppiness and overreaching one's abilities are especially fatal in an interview.

Comment: [Interview question: The Two-Sum Problem](http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs9/lectures/06/TwoSum.pdf)  (older variant of the problem @ stanford.edu)